# mysql database host

Tags: mysql, hosting

Like there's "shared website host", I hope there's a database host.
It's like getting an IP, user name and password and just connecting to that database.

I think that would be better instead of trying to setup such a server - rent dedicated server, configure software (prone to many errors).

So I'm looking for this company that take this seriously and have a cluster (for reliability) of MySQL servers from which I can rent some allocation.

Oh, and I'm looking for this service in Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are for MongoDB but a remote MySQL setup like that would add a lot of latency in your application. Might not be worth it

Comment: Thought about it - if the server is in Europe I'll be able to "suffer" it... See, NL got great linkage (: